# Rust mock function returning reference using `mockall`

Tags: unit-testing, rust, mocking

The code that I'm trying to mock is similar to this (this is just a minimal example):

```rust
use std::any::Any;

struct Foo {
    data: Box<dyn Any>,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn bar<T: 'static>(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        self.data.downcast_ref()
    }
}
// (other impls for `Foo`)
```

and it compiled, no errors.

I tried to mock it like so:

```rust
use mockall::mock;

mock! {
    pub Foo {
        pub fn bar<T: 'static>(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&T>;
    }
}
```

but I got an error:

```
error[E0637]: `&` without an explicit lifetime name cannot be used here
 --> src/main.rs:6:63
  |
6 |         pub fn bar<T: 'static>(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&T>;
  |                                                               ^ explicit lifetime name needed here

error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:6:63
  |
6 |         pub fn bar<T: 'static>(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&T>;
  |                                                               ^ expected named lifetime parameter
  |
  = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value with an elided lifetime, but the lifetime cannot be derived from the arguments
  = note: for more information on higher-ranked polymorphism, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html
help: consider making the bound lifetime-generic with a new `'a` lifetime
  |
4 ~ for<'a> mock! {
5 |     pub Foo {
6 ~         pub fn bar<T: 'static>(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&'a T>;
  |
help: consider using the `'static` lifetime
  |
6 |         pub fn bar<T: 'static>(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&'static T>;
  |                                                               ~~~~~~~~
```

I tried adding the `'static` lifetime and it compiled but I don't think that's what I want because https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/static_lifetime.html says that

> As a reference lifetime 'static indicates that the data pointed to by the reference lives for the entire lifetime of the running program.

and I don't think thats what I want because I don't see any reason for the returned reference to have to live for the lifetime of the entire program.

Also, now `bar` on the new mock type is slightly different to `bar` on the original type. I feel like this could cause some problems elsewhere where I'm using lifetimes.

Comment: Have you considered making the function generic over the lifetime?

Comment: Good question. @BlackBeans I tried, but didn't manage to get it to work

Comment: @Finomnis I have to admit my laziness refrains me from setting up a small example to try with `mockall`, but maybe something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9467a0a8d6b35f409ff6e071f6a7976f) should be enough?

Comment: @BlackBeans Yes, I understand what you meant. Please try with `mockall` and see for yourself instead of just posting random guesses.

Comment: @Finomnis I guess I'll have to get over my lazyness :/ I tried and... it didn't work. Then, I read the documentation (feels like I did the things in the right order), and found [this](https://docs.rs/mockall/latest/mockall/#methods-with-generic-lifetimes), where it says " Another is that the generic lifetime may not appear as part of the return type. Finally, no method may have both generic lifetime parameters and generic type parameters.", so there are two reasons for which this won't work.

Comment: Yah, I feared as much after glancing over the docs. Didn't find the "no method may have both" line, though. I agree this pretty much answers the question.

Comment: mock is used in test so I don't see why 'static lifetime would be a problem